# Developing an Android Client Server app

Tags: android, client-server

I am developing an app as follows:
 Android APP (As a client)..it will send data to a Server (Java application running on a PC).
I implemented this using socket programming and it is working. I have following issues:

1. When I click the send button on my app the APP UI freezes for ~7 seconds. It is able to ping and connect to server but during this time frame the UI freezes and if I click any other button on the app I get a message app is stuck (but the app comes back ok after ~ 7 seconds). What is the best way to resolve it.
2. Once data (strings) is received on the PC, I want to show it in the form of List Box UI so that user can select/double click on the specific string and a message box is open showing that that particular string is selected. What is the best way to develop this UI and how can it be invoked directly as soon as server receives the data from Client (android app) and this UI should show up.

Please let me know. All help is appreciated.

Comment: For 1: Use an `AsyncTask` so you don't freeze the UI and don't get `NetworkOnMainthreadException`s Also, this question isn't very well suited here, we expect questions to be backed by some kind of trial (hence the popular question *"What have you tried?"*).

Comment: if the background process is long-running its not advisable to use AsyncTask. It can be simply implemented in a separate thread or a service (which has worked for me in developing a similar app).

Comment: regarding your second question, do you want to do that on the client i.e android side? if you want something like that on the client side then you can make the server application send a notification to the client once it receives some data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried using it in the Activity and also used socket program for client server connectivity. For 2nd issue I want it to implement it on Server side. Please advise..thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Place all your network-related code into a separate thread, or (easier) and [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Otherwise, you would block the UI, as you have noticed, and the app would actually crash on newer Android versions (ICS and JB).

If you search SO and the interwebs, you will find plenty of examples.